# How to make this show/hide script work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to javascript. I wrote a simple show/hide off canvas script with my noobie knowledge. It works but not quite the way I want it to. I want the left `#mySidenav` to be displayed when user login. It's working but it's hiding the actual dashboard content because `#main` behaves like `#mySidenav` is closed. How can I make this work?

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Employees</a>
  <a href="#">Schedules</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Timesheets</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Admin Dashboard</h2>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: To hide an element, don't bother with setting the `width` and `margin` and colors, just set `display:none;` via a class. Then, remove the class when you want the element back.

Comment: maybe you want this?

document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: this what you're trying to do? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZRKOG

Comment: @MichaelCoker: Yup. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MartinMars NP, I'll submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to add the `openNav()` change to the default HTML/CSS so that the `openNav()` state is what you see when the page loads.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Employees</a>
  <a href="#">Schedules</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Timesheets</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Admin Dashboard</h2>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open sidenav by default, you have to add `margin-left` for `#main`. Try this:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
}
#main {
        transition: margin-left .5s;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-left:250px;
}
```

If you want to close by default:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Working JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9u9hb839/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="width:0;">
```

or

```
.sidenav {
   width: 0px;
}
```

set the width to 0 and it will stop the default opening of sidenav on pageload

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to change the `width:250px` to `width:0px` in `.sidenav`

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
}
```

It'll prevent the default opening of the sidenav.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Employees</a>
  <a href="#">Schedules</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Timesheets</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Admin Dashboard</h2>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this?

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Employees</a>
  <a href="#">Schedules</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Timesheets</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Admin Dashboard</h2>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CSS classes when possible, instead of directly using values in your JS. This is better to avoid repetition of your styles everywhere, and to make your code more maintainable. Here is how I would do it:

Add a `.nav-open` class to the body

```
<body class="nav-open">
```

In your CSS, add these styles

```
.sidenav{
    width: 0;
}

body.nav-open {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

body.nav-open #main {
    margin-left: 250px;
}

body.nav-open .sidenav {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Change your JS to this:

```
function openNav() {
  // Add the class
  document.body.className += " nav-open ";
}

function closeNav() {
  // Remove the class
  document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\bnav-open\b/g,' ');
}
```

### Demo

```js
document.body.className = 'nav-open'; // Just for the demo

function openNav() {
  // Add the class
  document.body.className += " nav-open ";
}

function closeNav() {
  // Remove the class
  document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\bnav-open\b/g,' ');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
body.nav-open {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
}

body.nav-open #main {
    margin-left: 250px;
}

body.nav-open .sidenav {
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Employees</a>
  <a href="#">Schedules</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Timesheets</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Admin Dashboard</h2>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```